# Mobile Like Time Picker For React Web

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-dom

[image: Demo of the time picker]

I am trying to make an Alarm clock UI using react and I am stuck at this component where users can scroll or swipe through hours, minutes etc.. I tried some methods but failed.

I tried on scroll, on wheel, but my problem is I just can't get the accurate value which user sees(like the 03:30 PM).
I don't want you to help me with code, just need to know how to approach this.

Comment: is your problem is that you are not able to stop the scroll at the exact value, does it stops somewhere in between?

Comment: @KartikMalik No bro, actually, I can't understand how to implement this.

Comment: @KartikMalik Some of the options I tried was,
1. I used divs to render each hour and when user scrolls I took the the inner html.
2. OnClick  get the value.
But what I actually want is your can scroll through and whenever they stop the scroll, I should get that particular state.

Comment: Okay, I got your problem. I will try to address the solution in the answer section below, can you share your tech stack too. Is it Vanilla JS or you are using something like React?

Comment: @KartikMalik It's react bro

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would approach this problem like this

let's address the challenges here

1. Scrolling to the desired points only
2. Looped scrolling
3. Auto pick the Value - without clicking basically.

**Scrolling to the desired points only**

This concept is called snap scrolling, you can use some library for that avoid writing its logic by yourself because then you will end up handling a lots of edge cases.

**Looped scrolling**

You need to handle this using basic JS logic you can provide some extra buffer elements at the end and at the starting refer to this example

https://codepen.io/lemmin/pen/bqNBpK

```
window.onscroll = function () {
  // Horizontal Scroll.
  var y = document.body.getBoundingClientRect().top;
  page.scrollLeft = -y;
  
  // Looping Scroll.
  var diff = window.scrollY - dummy_x;
  if (diff > 0) {
    window.scrollTo(0, diff);
  }
  else if (window.scrollY == 0) {
    window.scrollTo(0, dummy_x);
  }
}
```

**Auto pick the Value**

one very basic approach could be, you can get the scroll offset on change of scroll, and as you have the height of every entity you can get the element that is in focus(or highlighted to the user).

Below is one more approach, you can create a selector div then you can check for the overlap on-scroll-stop whichever element is within this div, you can get its value.

[image: approach 2 refrence]

personally, I think the first approach will be simpler and more stable. I have seen people using both types of approaches.

let me know if could help with anything else.